# How to split column based on row value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I need a column from row value.

I have two table.

**Table 1 : working_day** Contains list of all working day date.

```
date
--------
2013-03-30
2013-03-29
2013-03-28
```

**Table 2 : entry** contains each employee in and out time.

```
id  In  Out  Date
1   9   0    2013-03-30
2   8   0    2013-03-30
3   7   0    2013-03-30
1   8   18   2013-03-29
2   9   16   2013-03-29
3   6   20   2013-03-29
4   12  15   2013-03-29
```

**Expected Output :**

```
ID  29-03-2013_IN  29-03-2013_Out   30-03-2013_In
1    8                    18          9
2    9                    16          8
3    6                    20          7
4    12                   15          0
```

Tried :

```
SELECT id, 
Case condition1 for 29_in,  // I don't know which condition suite here.
Case condition1 for 29_out,
Case condition1 for 30_in
FROM entry
WHERE DATE
IN (
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT DATE
FROM working_day
ORDER BY DATE DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 2
)a
)
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a group by clause, and that would get you the results you need, just not in the format you specified.

Comment: This article has a very nice howto do pivot in MySQL: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like that:

```
select 
   e.id,
   (SELECT `in` FROM entry WHERE id = e.id AND date = '2013-03-30') as '2013-03-30_in',
   (SELECT `in` FROM entry WHERE id = e.id AND date = '2013-03-29') as '2013-03-29_in',
   (SELECT `out` FROM entry WHERE id = e.id AND date = '2013-03-29') as '2013-03-29_out'
from entry e
group by e.id;
```

Here is [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4f76/6)

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should do this in application instead of SQL